# Как нормализовать данные с помощью MinMaxScaler()?

Tags: машинное-обучение, jupyter-notebook, sklearn

Имею фрейм данных с разными типами данных как-то: `int64`, `float64`, `object`.

Пытаюсь нормализовать данные с помощью `MinMaxScaler()`, вот так:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
names = train.columns
d = scaler.fit_transform(train)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=names)
scaled_df.head()
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> could not convert string to float: '00000bfd7d50f01092811bc0c8d7b0d6fe7c3596'

Это признак 'ID' клиента. Как мне нормализовать только числовые данные с помощью `MinMaxScaler`?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [этим ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46657317/8324991), чтобы получить только данные из числовых колонок:

```
import numpy as np

df_numerics_only = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
```

Либо получить названия этих числовых колонок:

```
colnames_numerics_only = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.tolist()
```